# Как получить измененные данные в knockout.js?

Tags: javascript, knockoutjs

Добрый день, есть модель у которой практически все поля observable

```
var ViewModel = function () {
        var self = this;
        self.sklades = ko.observableArray(
        [
            {

                id: ko.observable("1"),
                name: ko.observable("Имя склада"),
                tovcount: ko.observable("1234567890"),
                status: ko.observable("1"),

            }
        ]
    );
        self.hasChanges = ko.computed(function() {

        console.log(ko.toJSON(self.sklades));
    });
};
```

Модель привел не полностью, но полей в ней намного больше. Можно-ли как-либо получить именно то значение, которое изменилось, чтобы обойтись без перечисления всех observable полей и сравнения их со старыми значениями?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Полагаю, что это еще прототип, можно многое себе позволить. Но все же инициализацию проводить лучше как-нибудь так:

```
function Sklad(params){
  for(var fld in params){
    this[fld]=ko.observable(params[fld]);
  }
}

function ViewModel(sklades){
  this.sklades=ko.observableArray(sklades.map(function(sklad){
    return new Sklad(sklad);
  }));
}
```

Теперь на каждое поле можно легко подписаться:

```
  this[fld]=ko.observable(params[fld]);
  //вызываем onUpdateField на каждое обновление
  this[fld].subscribe(this.onUpdateField.bind(this, fld));
```

`onUpdateField` :

```
Sklad.prototype.onUpdateField=function(fld, newValue){
    alert('sklad ' + this.id() + ': ' + fld + ' = '+newValue);
    // -> sklad 1: tovcount = <новое значение>
}
```

[попробовать](https://jsfiddle.net/z9rhsbkx/)

Comment: О, спасибо, а тогда еще вопрос:
вот к примеру мне нужно на click биндить функиии, мне,  получается их просто во 
function ViewModel(sklades){
  }));
}
писать?

Comment: Вопрос не очень понятен. [Здесь](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html), надеюсь, найдете ответ. Кроме того, для легкого старта есть отличные [туториалы](http://learn.knockoutjs.com).

Comment: да, с предыдущим комментарием я перестарался. Вот такой вопрос возник, [и видимо не одного меня](http://goo.gl/6Nf5sR)

Вот смотрите, с какой проблемой столкнулся: я не могу понять как подписаться на новые данные в массиве, то есть когда я дополняю или вообще заполняю заново данными из AJAX 
[пример](https://jsfiddle.net/28L1uyy3/5/)

Comment: можно [так](https://jsfiddle.net/28L1uyy3/6/). Можно привлечь [ko.wrap](https://github.com/arj03/knockout.wrap) и подписываться в коллбэке `computedFunctions`.